# How to fix mysqldatareader in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this address book program in vb.net. You need to create your account first before you can access the whole system. When I create an account and I log in, it works. But when I stop the program, run it again and try to log in the account that I just created. It doesn't work anymore. But when I create a new one and log it in it let's me access the system. What should I do? Is there something wrong with my program? Please help me.

I already tried playing with the if-else, while. Btw, the password is encrypted.

```vb
Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

    Dim conn As New CONNECTION_MANAGER()
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim dataR As MySqlDataReader
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `loginUser` WHERE `username` = @usn AND `password` = @pass", conn.getConnection())

    conn.openConnection()
    command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxUsername.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EncryptData(TextBoxPassword.Text)


    If TextBoxUsername.Text.Trim() = "" Or TextBoxUsername.Text.Trim() = "username" Then
        MessageBox.Show("ユーザー名を入力してください！", "ユーザー名が見つかりません", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    ElseIf TextBoxPassword.Text.Trim() = "" Or TextBoxPassword.Text.Trim() = "password" Then
        MessageBox.Show("パスワードを入力してください!", "パスワードが見つかりません", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Else
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(table)
        conn.openConnection()
        dataR = command.ExecuteReader

        If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            While dataR.Read
                Me.Hide()
                Dim mainForm As New DisplayForm()
                mainForm.UsernamePass = TextBoxUsername.Text
                mainForm.Show()
            End While
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ユーザー名とパスワードが存在しません", "ログインエラー", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's what my EncryptData function looks like

```vb
Public command As New MySqlCommand

Public datar As MySqlDataReader

Private tripleDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider


Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String) As String
    Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)
    Dim memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(memStream, tripleDes.CreateEncryptor(),
                         System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
    encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray)

End Function
```

I expect my program to let the created users login again because it is already registered in the database.

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work anymore".  What exactly do you mean?  Are you getting an exception? Unintended behaviour?

Comment: Why are you populating a `DataTable` and using a data reader?

Comment: @Hursey when I exit the program and run it again, the user that I just registered can't log in anymore. It says it doesn't exist in the database but when I check my database it is recorded.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'm sorry im just new to vb.net so i don't really undertsand much. Is data reader used to read encrypted values?

Comment: Well, that would lead me to suspect that either the value of usn and/or pass parameters are incorrect.  Really that's all we can offer. perhaps try the process without any sort of encryption to ensure it works with plain text

Comment: I would also do some reading on ado.net and data access.  What jmchilhinney says is correct.  You are making two trips to the DB to get the same data.  And appears you are leaving your DB connection open.  Look at the Using clause to tidy up your connections after you've finished with it

Comment: *"Is data reader used to read encrypted values"*. A data reader is used to read data.  The encryption part is irrelevant. As suggested, you really ought to do appropriate reading to learn how to use ADO.NET properly first. A `DataTable` provides random access to data read from a database. If you need to edit and save changes then populate it using a data adapter, otherwise with a data reader. Using a data reader without a `DataTable` gives you read-only, forward-only access to the data.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should be using hashing for passwords. You only need one function to hash a password and it gets used for registering and logging in. On registration, you hash the password and save the result. On logging in, you hash the password and compare to the value stored in the database. Lots of information around about hashing and salting passwords.

Comment: When user created his account, does the system automatically log him in without going through the login code you showed above?

Comment: @ajakblackgoat no. It goes to login form first and it works when I login using the created account. but when I close the forms and run program again. it doesn't let the created account log in unless you create a new account again

Comment: sorry im a really new programmer and i don't know how to fix this